# With Chrome how to use the the javascript: URL pseudoprotocol?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

With Firefox I can type in the location bar "javascript:" followed by some JavaScript code and have this code executed and the result displayed in the page. For example `javascript:x = 3` displays `3` in the page.

However with Chrome nothing is displayed. Is there a way to do this in Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
javascript:x=3;alert(x)
```

Or:

```
javascript:x=3;document.write(x)
```

At least on Chrome for OS X, neither of these work on the new tab page; you must first open any other page first. Loading `about:blank` does just fine.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for me.  Or it doesn't work if I *paste* the string.  Typing it in seems to work.  Google's autocomplete seems to be interfering and won't turn off.  Makes it feel like IE.

Comment: chrome doesn't like spaces: so `javascript: x=3; alert(x);` is different from `javascript:x=3; alert(x)`. The former doesn't work, the latter does.

Answer (score 0):

Start Chrome with the `--enable-user-scripts` command line option.

Then `javascript:` URLs will work fine!

Comment: This is not actually necessary, at least on OS X. Entering `javascript:window.alert("hello");` works just fine without it.